# How to assign a string value

Tags: c, string, scanf

Can I do something like the code below to get a persons name into the firstname string?

```
printf("First Name? ");
scanf("%s", &firstname[11]);
```

Comment: I am using c programming

Comment: Are you sure you want to start at index 11?

Comment: Now, I wasn't sure if it'd start at index 11 or would only allow the field to be 11 spaces.

Comment: Beware though, the user could easily input too many characters, resulting in a buffer overflow. If you want to limit the number of characters scanned in, put that into the format string for `scanf`.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: "%10s" if the buffer is 11 `char` long. (10+terminator) For reference: [C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: For your next question, consider submitting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Especially variable declarations are always of interest. Have fun.

Comment: "Now, I wasn't sure if it'd start at index 11 or would only allow the field to be 11 spaces" -- then you really need to learn more basics about C programming.

Comment: The class I'm in is Intro to "C", so I'm just getting started on learning the ins and outs of this language.

Comment: Then read those portions of the course material -- or check with your instructor -- dealing with the meaning of `&filename[11]` -- this is very important to understand.

Answer (score 2):

**yup.** This stores the input in `firstname`, starting at index `11`.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** You should not do it this way.  It is **unsafe**, in exactly the same way [`gets` is unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

You should instead do something like this.  (I am assuming that you really do want to write to `firstname` starting at character position 11, which is what `&firstname[11]` does.  If `firstname` is 11 bytes long and you want to write starting at position 0, you would simply use `firstname` and remove the various occurrences of `11 +` below.)

```
char inbuf[80];
size_t n;

fputs("First Name? ", stdout);
fgets(inbuf, sizeof inbuf, stdin);

n = strlen(inbuf);
if (n == 0) {
  fputs("No name entered\n", stderr);
  exit(1);
}
if (inbuf[n-1] != '\n') {
  fputs("Name too long\n", stderr);
  exit(1);
}
inbuf[--n] = '\0';
if (n == 0) {
  fputs("No name entered\n", stderr);
  exit(1);
}
if (11 + n >= sizeof firstname) {
  fputs("Name too long\n", stderr);
  exit(1);
}

memcpy(&firstname[11], inbuf, n);
firstname[11 + n] = '\0';
```

If you reaction is that that looks like a giant pain in the behind, all I can say is, welcome to C programming.  All of that is in fact necessary for robustness in the face of arbitrarily malformed input.

You should also reflect upon [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and then redesign your database accordingly.  (Most importantly in this context: people do not necessarily divide their names into "first" and "last" and "middle" components; many people have first names that require more than 10 bytes to represent.)

**EDIT:** Bugs in example code should now all be corrected.  Serve me right for doing memory arithmetic in my head without testing it.

Comment: I don't think the OP really wants to store into firstname + 11 ... I think firstname is only 11 chars (or maybe only 10 plus NUL) ... see the comments under the question.

Comment: `memcpy(&firstname[11], inbuf, n+1);` Also `f (inbuf[n-1] != '\n' ...)` will cause problems when n happens to be zero.

Comment: @wildplasser That's not right either, because `n` includes the newline. Try `inbuf[n-1] = '\0'; strcpy(firstname, inbuf);`

Comment: No. fgets() can hit a binary NUL or EOF before seeing a '\n'.

Comment: @wildplasser Sigh. See the explicit check (and exit) for that. And even if it *can*, in the normal case you will be copying the newline into firstname.

Comment: Sigh. `memcpy(&firstname[11], inbuf, n);` would not NUL-terminate the string.

Comment: @Wildplasser What part of "not right *either*" don't you understand? of course Zack's code is wrong TOO. Stop being such a kneejerk and take a little more time to think. What I wrote is completely true so you have no reason to sigh at it, just fix your mistake. I'm out of here.

Comment: What part of `n` can be zero, so `inbuf[n-1]` will be an illegal access don't you understand ? And that illegal array indexing takes place _before_ the exit.

Comment: @wildplasser All the bugs in my example code should now be fixed.  Thanks for pointing them out, I should know better than to scribble code in the answer box without testing it at all.

Comment: @wildplasser ?? I do repeat that test!

Comment: @wildplasser "What part of n can be zero, so inbuf[n-1] will be an illegal access don't you understand ?" -- I understand it all, which is why I didn't disagree with it. It has nothing at all to do with any of what I wrote. All I said is that `memcpy(&firstname[11], inbuf, n+1);` was wrong because it would copy the newline (which will *always* be present because of the exit if it isn't). And that remains true despite all your misdirections. I never said that any of Zack's errors you pointed out *weren't* errors (I explicitly said *so*), so it's bizarre that you write as if I had.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is, yes you can.

The long answer (and questions that go with it)...

What's the declaration of `firstname`?

What's in the first `11` places of `filename`?

Are you trying to limit the the limit the length of the user input to `11` characters and that was the syntax you thought would work?

I suspect that you are trying to limit the `firstname` to be at most `11` characters. The way to solve this is:

```
char firstname[12];
scanf("%11s", firstname);
```

However, as Zach pointed out, this will be problematic if you have a first name like "Mary Kay". `scanf` will stop at the first white space and you will end up with a first name that contains just "Mary". The better approach is to use `fgets`.

```
fgets(firstname, 12, stdin);
```

That should work if there is nothing else in a line.

If you expect to read the data from a file and there are other fields in a line, then you will have to deal with that additional complexity. Say you have first name, last name, and age in a line. Your input file could look something like:

```
John, Deer, 59
Mary Kay, Smith, 42
```

If your input file contains data like above, you can't use `fgets` to pick out the first name using `fgets(firstname, 12, infile);`. You will have to use `fgets` to read the entire line, then parse the line to extract all the relevant data.

Comment: I would upvote this if you suggested `fgets`, but none of the `scanf` functions should ever be used, period.

Comment: Even this apparently-reasonable use is problematic because (a) you have to write out the buffer size in two places, (b) it stops at whitespace and therefore *will* require further effort to clear a trailing newline, (c) it stops at whitespace and therefore will mangle first names with a space in them (e.g. "Mary Kay").

Comment: @Zack, thanks for inspiring me to expand the answer to cover a few more scenarios.